# SSL TCP Client in .NET CF?

Tags: .net, ssl, compact-framework

In .NET CF 3.5 (on Windows CE 5.0), i wanna send receive data to/from a server over TCP.
How can i implement SSL TCP client for that issue?
It seems that .NET framework full version supports SSL , but not in CF!
I read similar articles and posts , googled for workarounds , sample codes, and free components but got nothing.

could anybody plz tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ported the [Mentalis SecureSocket library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/ssocket/) to the CF for our internal use.  The port was not terribly difficult.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [SSLBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssl.php) package of our SecureBlackbox. SecureBlackbox provides complete SSL support on .NET CF as well as on Silverlight and Windows Phone.